# TabHost vs TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tabs

Пытаюсь сделать меню с табами  и вижу что в примерах используют TabHost и TabLayout. В чем принципиальная разница между ними, и что сейчас предпочтительней использовать под такую задачу!

1. возможность запретить скроллирование
2. возможность вместо текста вставить иконку в таб
3. возможность динамически добавлять\удалять табы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TabLayout` - самая свежая реализация табов. Используйте её. 2 и 3 пункты там точно можно делать, для первого же попробуйте в деле аттрибут `scrollable`

Comment: с первым пунктом если использовать ViewPager - я разобрался. А вот по поводу добавлениея удаления мне пока что  встречались только под TabHost туториалы, может есть ссылочка на пример ?

Comment: @KirillStoianov, вот про [иконки](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30914445/3212712)

Comment: @KirillStoianov, добавлять табы тоже просто: `tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB"));`

Answer (score 0):

Пример для добовления вкладок через TabHost:

```
  findViewById(R.id.add_tab).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addTab();
        }
    });

}

private void addTab(){
    LayoutInflater layoutInflate = LayoutInflater.from(Main_Activity.this);
    Button tabBtn = (Button)layoutInflate.inflate(R.layout.tab_event, null);
    tabBtn.setText("Tab ");
    Intent tabIntent = new Intent(Main_Activity.this, TabActivity.class);
    TabHost.TabSpec setContent = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab").setIndicator(tabBtn).setContent(tabIntent);
    tabHost.addTab(setContent);
}
```

TabActivity class:

```
public class TabActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView tv = new TextView(TabActivity.this);
    tv.setText("Tab activity");
    setContentView(tv);
   }
}
```